# query for the most recently proceeding record

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

There are records in an Eligibility Table [ET] for Eligible [Eg] and Ineligible [In].  Each record only has one date attached to it.  I have Customer Services [CS] in a Services Table [ST] that I need to determine what type of record most recently preceeded the service date.

---

```
______________ET______________



Eg    01.01.2012  
In    01.20.2012  
Eg    01.29.2012  
In    02.10.2012  

_________________________ST______________________________  

CS  Joe Schmoe  02.01.2012 11:00 AM  
CS  Joe Schmoe  01.25.2012 1:00  PM  
CS  Harold Doe  02.09.2012 4:00  PM
```

---

I want to return the fact that the service for Joe Schmoe on 02.01.2012 11:00 AM were eligible because of an eligibility record on 01.01.2012, Joe Schmoe was ineligible for services on 01.25.2012 1:00  PM because of an ineligibility record on 01.20.2012, and Harold Schmoe was eligible for services on 02.09.2012 4:00  PM because of an eligibility record on 01.29.2012.

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*RESULTS****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Joe Schmoe  02.01.2012 11:00 AM Eligible   01.01.2012
Joe Schmoe  01.25.2012 1:00  PM Ineligible 01.20.2012
Harold Doe  02.09.2012 4:00  PM Ineligible 01.29.2012

Comment: Your result example and your description seem to contradict each other.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, eligibility is either on or off.  If a service date is in an on period, it is eligible.  If it is in an off period is is not. That right?

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c73b/5

```
select fname, etdate, 'eligible' as eligible
from st
where  etdate between 
(select max(etdate) from et where status ='Eg')
and
(select max(etdate) from et where status ='In')
union
select fname, etdate, 'ineligible' as eligible
from st
where  etdate not between 
(select max(etdate) from et where status ='Eg')
and
(select max(etdate) from et where status ='In')
order by 2
```

Comment: Use UNION ALL since you won't have dupes. Also not sure that this is correct - you're just looking at the last In/Eg rows. If you had an etdate of 1/10/12, they'd be "ineligible" - even though the effective record on 1/10 was "eligible".

Answer (score 2):

`apply` was designed for this.

```
select
    ST.fName, stETD = ST.etDate, previousET.*
from
    ST
    outer apply (
        select top 1
            ET.Status,
            ET.ETDate
        from
            ET
        where
            ET.ETDate <= ST.etDate
        order by
            ET.ETDate desc
    ) previousET
order by
    2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c73b/11

This will get you the most recently (`order by ETDate desc`) proceeding record (`where ETDate <= ST.Date`). Thanks to [mikeY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10856588/40822) for fiddle.

Comment: That works in my fiddle if you clean up the column names. Very cool.

Comment: +1 for clarity, though I generally dislike correlated subqueries (which is basically what the apply boils down to)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a unique constraint on UserId and Date in the eligibility table (otherwise, you'll need another tiebreaker such as adding a row_number over userid, date), you:

- JOIN to all records that have a date less than the date you're interested in (the CS date)
- You then take the maximum of those dates (since you want the last date that is prior to the event)
- You then JOIN back to the original table to get the rest of the row details (the status type). This is why you need the unique constraint

> 

```
SELECT
   UserId, Date, Status, ETDate
FROM (
    --The last matching status record by date
    SELECT ST.UserId, ST.Date, MAX(ET.Date) as ETDate
    FROM ST
    JOIN ET ON
       ST.UserId = ET.UserId
       AND CS.Date >= ET.Date
    GROUP BY
       ST.UserId, ST.Date
) as C
JOIN ET as E ON
    C.UserId = E.UserId
    AND C.ETDate = E.ETDate
```

Comment: There is no CS table and there is no userid in the ET table.  Could you walk through this for those of us who are apparently painfully slow?

Comment: @mikeY - Sorry - s/CS/ST. Absent schema info, I'm assuming the join should be on UserId. If Eligible/Ineligible is a "global" value, should be simple enough to just remove UserId from the join (and you'd still need a unique constraint on date).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd request, because elibility is not at the user level.

The following query does what you want:

```
select et.*, st.elibility, st.ETDate
from et cross join
     (select st.*
      from st join
           (SELECT MAX(cs.Date) as lastcsDate
            FROM st JOIN
                 et
                 ON st.Date <= et.Date
            GROUP BY cs.UserId
           ) t
           on st.date = t.lastcsDate
     ) lastst
```

Note:  I haven't run this query to forgive any typos.

This uses a correlated subquery to get the most recent date on or before each date in the et table.  The rest is just joining in the right information for the select clause.